# unknown property 'optimization'

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I'll trying to use uglify with webpack but got this error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'optimization'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
```

I have

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
```

and

```
optimization: {
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
    }
```

in my webpack.config.js, looks like webpack is not recognizing 'optimization'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you are using an old webpack version (3?) and you might need to put the plug-in instance in the `plugin` property:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [new UglifyJSPlugin()]
};
```

Always try to find documentation matching the version you are using or update webpack to a newer version. The current version is 4.19.0 (at 2018-09-17).

Comment: thanks, but i ran webpack --v and got 5.6.0, i think newest? i tried the plugin line but no luck, says .../webpack.js:315
  throw e;
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
    at UglifyJsPlugin.apply (.../node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:321:20)

Comment: Weirdly reinstalling webpack made it work now. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Same happened to me as well, please clear your node_modules and re-install them.